# How to parse span with beautiful soup if in final html it's hidden by javascript?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The goal is to get clothe's rating (stars) via beautiful soup.

For more clear detail this is part of python code, and in the past it worked:

```
    url = f"https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/18645227/detail.aspx?targetUrl=IN"
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser') 
    print(soup)
    rating = soup.find('span', {'data-link': 'text{: product^star}'})
```

in inspector google chrome can see html:

```
<span data-link="text{: product^star}">5</span>
```

but if to see it via print (or via view-source in chrome):

```
print(soup)
```

we'll see nothing like this:

```
 <span data-link="text{: product^star}">5</span>
```

in that place of html (via print(soup)) where must be body in html i can see just something like react stuff:

```
    <div id="mainContainer" class="main__container">
    
    <div id="app">
    </div>

    <button class="btn-quick-nav j-quicknav" type="button">to the 
    top</button>

    </div>
```

and huge bunch of javascript stuff in footer, so i can't pull that span

concrete url for example:

```
https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/18645227/detail.aspx?targetUrl=IN
```

concrete  to parse

```
<span data-link="text{: product^star}">4</span>
```

is it new tecnology comufliaging code protecting from parsing)?
is it any way to get "old-school html")?

Comment: Can you please share concrete URL? In your code snippet is missing the `i` variable

Comment: Sites often generate their contents via javascript in the browser. Check `response.text` first if it has the element. If it doesn't, find how the site generates the element and use its data source directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is *you can't* parse and/or get that data with `bs4`.

As you've noticed, all of the product's data is generated dynamically, which means you need to have a way of running `JavaScript`, which `bs4` doesn't do.

If you want to get the *old school HTML*, use automated tools like `selenium` with, for example, [Chrome driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started).

However, you can get the data *without* `selenium`, if you know the product's id.

Here's an example (the product id is the last value in the url `nm=51728993`):

```py
import requests

url = "https://wbxcatalog-ru.wildberries.ru/nm-2-card/catalog?spp=0&pricemarginCoeff=1.0&reg=0&appType=1&emp=0&locale=ru&lang=ru&curr=rub&nm=51728993"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0"
}
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()["data"]["products"][0]
print(f"{data['name']}\n{data['rating']} stars from {data['feedbacks']} reviews.")
```

Outputs:

```
Смартфон Poco M4 Pro / 6.6'' / 1080x2400 / IPS / 8 ГБ / 128 ГБ / 5000 мА*ч
5 stars from 414 reviews
```

Comment: Oh, man, thanks for explanation and wbxcatalog i didn't know) . That's way far much faster)